# execute a code after the page is loaded completely or delay the execution of the code

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#upcomeEvent').length > 0)
        $('#upcomeEvent').insertAfter('#eventBanner');
});
```

> execute a code after the page is loaded completely or delay the execution of the code
>
> I need to execute `$('#upcomeEvent').insertAfter('#eventBanner');` after the page is loaded completely
>   Another requirement is to delay the execution of `$('#upcomeEvent').insertAfter('#eventBanner');` by, say around 10 seconds.
>   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#upcomeEvent').insertAfter('#eventBanner');
},10000); // 10 second delay
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#upcomeEvent').length > 0)

    var timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#upcomeEvent').insertAfter('#eventBanner');                  
    },10000);

});
```